# What would make an append-only table remain in the buffer cache in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2017

We have a table that is pretty much append-only. It's not overly huge (~4M rows, ~1.4GB data)

It's the largest object in the buffer cache, consuming ~1.4GB of data.

The SQL Server is busy, but appears relatively healthy.

I'm wondering why it's always in the buffer cache? Surely there are better things to put in there?

When I search `sys.dm_exec_sql_text` for a reference to my table, I see a few of these entries.

```
INSERT INTO [Feedback].[UserEvents]
    ([CreatedOn], [EventName],[MetaData], [SessionCorrelationId],
    [UserContext], [UserAggregateId], [UserName])
VALUES (@p0, @p1, @p2, @p3, @p4, @p5, @p6)
SELECT [UserEventId]
FROM [Feedback].[UserEvents]
WHERE @@ROWCOUNT = 1 AND [UserEventId] = scope_identity()
```

Which is obviously EF doing the insert and getting the PK back.  UserEventId is both the clustered index and PK, and is an int(identity)

The table is not pinned (according to `OBJECTPROPERTY([id], 'TableIsPinned')`)

I've observed this for a few days, but it may have been going on much longer.

Here is the query that indicates it is in the buffer pool:

```
SELECT
    indexes.name AS index_name,
    objects.name AS object_name,
    objects.type_desc AS object_type_description,
    COUNT(*) AS buffer_cache_pages,
    COUNT(*) * 8 / 1024  AS buffer_cache_used_MB
FROM sys.dm_os_buffer_descriptors
INNER JOIN sys.allocation_units
ON allocation_units.allocation_unit_id = dm_os_buffer_descriptors.allocation_unit_id
INNER JOIN sys.partitions
ON ((allocation_units.container_id = partitions.hobt_id AND type IN (1,3))
OR (allocation_units.container_id = partitions.partition_id AND type IN (2)))
INNER JOIN sys.objects
ON partitions.object_id = objects.object_id
INNER JOIN sys.indexes
ON objects.object_id = indexes.object_id
AND partitions.index_id = indexes.index_id
WHERE allocation_units.type IN (1,2,3)
AND objects.is_ms_shipped = 0
AND dm_os_buffer_descriptors.database_id = DB_ID()
GROUP BY indexes.name,
         objects.name,
         objects.type_desc
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC;
```

And here is the query that I'm using to validate what activity is taking place on the table (and that it's *almost* insert only):

```
with myCTE as 
(
SELECT  SUBSTRING(qt.TEXT, (qs.statement_start_offset/2)+1,
((CASE qs.statement_end_offset
WHEN -1 THEN DATALENGTH(qt.TEXT)
ELSE qs.statement_end_offset
END - qs.statement_start_offset)/2)+1) as qt,
qs.execution_count,
qs.total_logical_reads, qs.last_logical_reads,
qs.total_logical_writes, qs.last_logical_writes,
qs.total_worker_time,
qs.last_worker_time,
qs.total_elapsed_time/1000000 total_elapsed_time_in_S,
qs.last_elapsed_time/1000000 last_elapsed_time_in_S,
qs.last_execution_time

FROM sys.dm_exec_query_stats qs
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(qs.sql_handle) qt

)
select * from myCTE
where qt like '%userEvents%'
```

Comment: "pretty much append-only" but not *completely* append-only. It only takes one bad query to put the whole table in the buffer pool